# How to interpret a n-related change in coverage for model (simulation study)

Tags: simulation, dispersion, gamlss, coverage-probability

I have repeated measures data from `n_subjects` where each has `n_obs` number of measurements before and after some intervention, and there are two experimental groups.  I am interested in the influence of group on the change from pre to post so the model looks something like

`y ~ time + group:time`

and I am interested in the `group:time` interaction.

`time` is a numeric column and either 0 or 1 depending on whether it was from the pre or the post timepoint, respectively. `group` is a factor.

One of the models, that I otherwise like the performance of, has coverage (95% CI) which gets lower for a larger number of observations at each timepoint, but does not change depending on the number of subjects.

[image]

(horizontal line is at `y=0.95`, where the coverage ought to be. There are 150 simulations for each combination of `n_subjects` and `n_obs`. Error bars represent Monte Carlo standard error.)

I am struggling to interpret this and understand what can be changed about the model to improve the coverage. What information is the model missing out on that's leading it to be overly precise?

The model is not biased in either direction, and the ModSE/EmpSE is >1 but trending towards 1 for both larger `n_subjects` and `n_obs` (as I believe it ought to).

All metrics were calculated by the methods described in Tim Morris' paper [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.8086).

More possibly useful details about the model:
The data are log-normally distributed.  I am using the `gamlss` pkg in R and the parameter I'm interested in is the `group:time` interaction in the sigma model to investigate the effect of group on the change in within-subject variability. The model code is:

```
model <- gamlss::gamlss(
    formula=y ~ time + group:time + re(random=~1|subject),
    sigma.fo=~ time + group:time + re(random=~time|subject),
    family='LOGNO2',
    data=data
  )
```

Comment: Please include a link to the data and also the simulation code

Comment: How is the confidence interval for the `group:time` term in the sigma formula calculated?

Comment: @RobertLong Sorry for the delay, I've put the code on a repository here. 
https://github.com/RWParsons/simulation_study
The main function which performs a single simulation is `fx_do_one_sim` in data_grid_and_simulator.R

Comment: @COOLSerdash I boot strap samples from the multivariate normal distribution 10000 times and take the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles having put these back on the interpretable scale. See lines 227-256 of https://github.com/RWParsons/simulation_study/blob/main/src/models.R

Comment: Couple of thoughts: i) Are you sure you're comparing the confidence intervals to the correct value? You generate the data using `rlnorm` but `LOGNO2` has a different parametrization. $\mu$ for example in `LOGNO2` denotes the median, not the mean on the log-scale. ii) How is the coverage if you use `confint(..., parm = "", what = "sigma")`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @COOLSerdash.  For your first point, that's definitely something that I'll need to consider when later interpreting the mean model, but I'm not sure if that'd influence my current problem as I'm only interpreting the sigma model at the moment.  For ii), I just have done a quick test and I can get the confidence intervals for the `time:group2`  interaction but since there is a log-link for the sigma model, this isn't interpretable as absolute change in the sd, which is what I'm assessing coverage over. That's why I went down the path of the bootstrapping approach.